# QVector2D - rotation

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, transformation-matrix

I'm porting my code from Python 3 (using my own classes for vectors, polygons, line segments etc. including various operations related to those such as cross and dot product, norm, intersection, point in polygon check and so on) to Qt 5.7.

In Python I did all the math manually for better understanding. Now that I'm porting my algorithm to Qt C++ I was hoping that Qt offers at least the basic stuff (beyond cross and dot product that is) when it comes to vectors such as the ability to rotate a vector, translate it etc. From what I'm seeing things are lacking...A lot.

There is the `QMatrix4x4` which seems to be deprecated (I was only able to find something in the docs for Qt 4.8). The only thing I found on rotation is the [QTransform::rotate(...)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtransform.html#rotate). However this is for rotating the coordinate system. While mathematically I can adapt my algorithm to this way of doing things I would still prefer to do it following the convention on rotating around an arbitrary point that is **translate to origin**, **rotate** and at the end **invert the translation**.

Am I missing something or is this really not available for `QVector2D` (I have also checked `QVector3D` since one can easily convert a 2D to 3D vector (which btw is necessary if you want to use the function for cross product :D))?

**NOTE:** Using QML is not an option here. Everything needs to be C++ only.

Comment: "rotate a vector"?  You want to go from column major to row major?

Comment: Where in the universe did you see [`QMatrix4x4`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html) is deprecated?

Comment: @wasthishelpful Damn Qt documentation...Thanks a lot for pointing that out. You can post this as the answer btw.

Comment: @xaxxon Not `QVector` but `QVector2D` that is a vector (mathematically speaking) in 2D. @wasthishelpful already found the solution. I just missed the `QMatrix4x4` in the Qt documentation. *slapping myself in the face*

Comment: Ah, wait. `QMatrix4x4::rotate(...)` rotates a matrix around a vector using another matrix (the one defined by the passed angle as a parameter to that function). It doesn't rotate a vector. XD

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a fair amount of duplication in the Qt libraries when it comes to geometry. For this situation, you can use `QTransform` and `QPointF`:

```
QPointF pivot = ...;
float rotationInDegrees = ...;
QTransform rotationAroundPivot = QTransform()
    .translate(-pivot.x(), -pivot.y());
    .rotate(rotationInDegrees);
    .translate(pivot.x(), pivot.y());
QPointF rotatedPoint = rotationAroundPivot.map(point);
```